# I found a folder called: bitcoin-0.3.22 How do I open it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I would really appreciate if you could explain how do I open a folder called: bitcoin-0.3.22
I am no dev so please be gentle with the instructions :)
I used to buy BTC back in 2011 and I believe I sold them all but now when i found this folder i thought it wouldn't hurt to see what's in it.

Is it even a wallet?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> **a folder called: bitcoin-0.3.22**

With that name it is probably a folder containing a download of an early version of the Bitcoin software. It may be a kind of compressed file called a ZIP file which Windows Explorer treats as a kind of folder. It may be the results of extracting the contents of a zip file.

Bitcoin version 0.3.22 was [released](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.3.22) on 5th June 2011

That folder isn't a wallet, there's no money in it.

---

Any remaining money would be associated with a file named `wallet.dat` probably in your `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\` folder.  It may have been kept in a different place back ten years ago but that's where it is normally found in current versions.

[image: How to access APPDATA folder]

Comment: Thank you RedGrittyBrick, I appreciate your time!